# AWS Sagemaker Workflow pIpeline use the code stored in artifact created from Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, aws-codebuild

I have created a `sagemaker.workflow.pipeline.Pipeline` object, in which, there are couple of processing step where I am trying to reference to an s3 file path rather than a local file path, so that it won't upload files to s3 everytime the pipeline runs.

My question is, can I modify the `step` or `scriptprocessor` or `pipeline` object so that I can reference a code from artifact created from AWS Codebuild?

If not, can I use codebuild to first copy my local file to a specific S3 position (I am having permission issue so far) and then run the pipeline?

As your reference

```
...
step_data_ingest = ProcessingStep(
        name="DataIngestion",
        processor=sklearn_data_ingest_processor,
        inputs=[
            ProcessingInput(
                input_name="input_train_data",
                source=input_data, 
                destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/data/train"
            ),
            ProcessingInput(
                input_name="input_test_data",
                source=test_data, 
                destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/data/test"
            ),
            ProcessingInput(
                input_name="requirement_file",
                source=os.path.join(code_dir, "requirements.txt"), 
                destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/requirement"
            ),
        ],
        outputs=[
            ProcessingOutput(
                output_name="train", 
                source="/opt/ml/processing/output/train",
                destination=get_projection_s3_dir(experiment_dir, "datasets/train")
            ),
            ProcessingOutput(
                output_name="validation", 
                source="/opt/ml/processing/output/validation",
                destination=get_projection_s3_dir(experiment_dir, "datasets/validation")
            ),
            ProcessingOutput(
                output_name="test", 
                source="/opt/ml/processing/output/test",
                destination=get_projection_s3_dir(experiment_dir, "datasets/test")
            ),
            ProcessingOutput(
                output_name="sample", 
                source="/opt/ml/processing/output/sample",
                destination=get_projection_s3_dir(experiment_dir, "datasets/sample")
            ),
        ],
        code=os.path.join(code_dir, "data_ingestion.py"),
        # something like s3://some_code_dir/data_ingestion.py
        job_arguments = ["-c", country, 
                         "-v", train_val_split_percentage],
    )
...
```

What I expect to do is something like:

```
# in processing step or processor
ProcessingStep(
    ...
    code="data_ingestion.py"
    code_location="s3://some_artifact_bucket/buildartifact/fdskz.zip"

    ...
)
```

OR

```
# in processing step or processor
ProcessingStep(
    ...
    code="s3://some_artifact_bucket/buildartifact/fdsix/data_ingestion.py"
    ...
)
```

OR

```
# in buildspec.yml for codebuild
aws s3 sync ./code_dir/ s3://some_code_dir/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `ProcessingStep`, you can use an `S3 URI` as the code location, take a look on [this](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/9fc57555bba4fc1d33064478dc209a84a6726c57/src/sagemaker/workflow/steps.py#L374) for reference.